# Find all x such that : $x^{x^{x^3({x^{x^{3}}+1)}+3}}=3^{81}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, exponentiation

This was the question :

> Find all x such that :
>   $x^{x^{x^3({x^{x^{3}}+1)}+3}}=3^{81}$

By observation (error and trial) I was able to find that $x=\sqrt[3]3$ is a solution , also , I was able to prove that there are no other solutions for positive x . As , for $x\in (0,1)$ there can not be any solution as LHS is less than $1$ and RHS is greater than $1$ , and for $x\in (1,\infty)$ the function is strictly increasing so there can be only one solution in that range .

**But** I am not able to say anything certainly about negative x , if I plot this funtion on desmos , it does not plot anything in the second quadrant ( Clearly the function is not defined for almost all negative x , but there are some negative values of x for which the function **is** defined , I didn't understand why they were also not plotted at least , I saw the same thing with the function $x^x$ , is it that these functions are just not defined for negative input ?  ).

So , if anyone could help me in finding the negative solution (if there is any ) , or teach me any way to  **properly** prove (I mean it is very intuitive that there is no negative solution but I couldn't support it with a solid reasoning) that there are no solutions for negative x , that would really be a great help !

Thanks!

Comment: $x^x=e^{x\log x}$ and the domain of the $\log$ function is $x>0$.

Comment: @AndrewChin ,yes , but for instance $-2^{-2} = {1\over 4}$ , and I can't seem to find anything wrong with this either. So I am heavily confused about this , could you please put some more light on it ?

Comment: $-2^{-2}=-\frac14$ though.  You are simply taking the negative of the power.

Comment: @AndrewChin sorry , I meant $(-2)^{-2} ={1\over (-2)^2}= {1\over 4}$

Comment: It is simply part of the definition of the exponential _function_, and is separate from exponents as an operation.  See wiki:  [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function).

Comment: @AndrewChin I couldn't understand that statement , like if I take the function $f(x)=e^x$ ,  it is defined for negative x (and obviously it is an exponential function ), did you mean to say that the function $f(x)=x^x$ is conventionally defined for positive x only ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108921/discussion-between-arrow-and-andrew-chin).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, let $y=x^{x^3}$, we have
$$x^{x^{x^3(x^{x^3}+1)+3}}=x^{x^{x^3(x^{x^3}+1)}\cdot x^3}=(x^{x^3})^{(x^{x^3})^{(x^{x^3}+1)}}=y^{y^{y+1}}$$
let $z=y^y$, we have 
$$y^{y^{y+1}}=y^{y^y\cdot y}=(y^y)^{y^y}=z^z=3^{81}=(3^3)^{27}=27^{27}$$
So, we can get $z=27$ and thus $y=3$ and thus
$$x^{x^3}=3 \implies x^{3x^3}=3^3 \iff (x^3)^{x^3}=3^3$$
and we can let $m=x^3$ and get $m^m=3^3 \implies m=3 \implies x=\sqrt[3]{3}$

Note: I did say several times that $a^a=3^3\implies a=3$ or $b^b=27^{27} \implies b=27$, and yes it's true
because if 
$$a^a=b^b \implies a\ln(a)=b\ln(b)$$
and because $f(x)=x \ln(x)$ is increasing for all $x \ge 1$ 
$$a>b \implies \ln(a)>\ln(b) \implies a\ln(a)>b\ln(b)$$
we get that $f$ is injective for all $x \ge 1$ and thus $a \ln(a) = b \ln(b) \implies a=b$ for all $a,b \in [1, \infty)$

Comment: I got the same solution by trial and error, and also got that there are no positive solutions as function is increasing, then I had to worry about negative solutions (if any) , but your way is very nice , in the end it clearly showed that there can be no negative solutions , that helped , thanks !

Comment: @ARROW you're most welcome! By the way, I too learned by solving this. I don't know how, but I never used the fact that if a function is monotonic on some interval, it's injective on that interval.